# libchromiumcontent create patch files

Tags: git, diff, patch, electron

I am trying to make some changes to something called [libchromiumcontent](https://github.com/atom/libchromiumcontent). By looking at the files it looks like all changes made to the code is done via `.patch` files, which I have not seen before, an example of this file is:

**ffmpeg.patch**

```
diff --git a/ffmpeg.gyp b/ffmpeg.gyp
index 31997bc..741d37a 100755
--- a/ffmpeg.gyp
+++ b/ffmpeg.gyp
@@ -414,14 +414,6 @@
                     '_snprintf=avpriv_snprintf',
                     'vsnprintf=avpriv_vsnprintf',
                   ],
-                }],
-                ['target_arch == "x64"', {
-                  # TODO(wolenetz): We should fix this.  http://crbug.com/171009
-                  'msvs_disabled_warnings' : [
-                    4267
-                  ],
-                }],
-                ['ffmpeg_component == "shared_library"', {
                   # Fix warnings about a local symbol being inefficiently imported.
                   'msvs_settings': {
                     'VCCLCompilerTool': {
@@ -431,6 +423,14 @@
                       ],
                     },
                   },
+                }],
+                ['target_arch == "x64"', {
+                  # TODO(wolenetz): We should fix this.  http://crbug.com/171009
+                  'msvs_disabled_warnings' : [
+                    4267
+                  ],
+                }],
+                ['ffmpeg_component == "shared_library"', {
                   'sources': [
                     '<(shared_generated_dir)/ffmpeg.def',
               ],
```

So to my questions

1. What kind of file is this?
2. How is it made?
3. It is the right way to make changes in `libchromiumcontent`?

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the repo page, *libchromiumcontent* is the [content module](http://www.chromium.org/developers/content-module) (pictured below) of the Chrome browser. It's used by Electron, and therefore by Electron applications as a result. In order to support this, the Electron team routinely pull changes in from upstream, and *patches* them.

Brendan Forster [covered this in slightly more detail](https://youtu.be/oTDjyMTZU1s?t=414) during his "Walk Through Electron Internals" talk at NDC {Syndney}.

[image: Chrome content module]